# Storyboards only for iOS apps

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, storyboard

I was little surprised when I was reading Apple Documentation from this [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/Edit_User_Interfaces/edit_user_interface.html)

Which tells that

**A user interface file for an iOS app has the filename extension storyboard. A user interface file for a Mac app has the filename extension xib.**

I have used xib's in most of my projects and I still do the same which sometimes makes me little comfortable. Does this statement tells whether we should use only Storyboards in future ? Please share your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I work with some guys that still are uncomfortable with xibs in the way you may be with storyboards.  They like using what they are comfortable with, and they maintain older code bases.

I believe Apple has found that people develop cleaner apps more quickly with storyboards, and are pushing folks in that direction.  I don't see the removal of xibs any time in the foreseeable future, any more than I see people restricted from completely being able to to programatically create the entire app.  You still have the option of using storyboards or not, and if not, its certainly easy to use xib's.

I was really hesitant about the storyboards, so my latest new project I decided to just dive in 100% on storyboards, and I was stunned at how happy I am with them and with segues.  The communication between storyboards, the prototype cells in UITableViews and the visual linking of the ViewControllers really helped me.

Comment: Thanks HaIR. I am in a same position like you, hesitant to use the Storyboards for my future projects. Will give it a try for Storyboard to see how it works..